# How can I assign bucket-owner-full-control when creating an S3 object with boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm using the Amazon boto3 library in Python to upload a file into another users bucket. The bucket policy applied to the other users bucket is configured like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3BucketList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::uuu"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bbb"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3ObjectUpload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::uuu"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bbb",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bbb/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

where `uuu` is my user id and `bbb` is the bucket name belonging to the other user. **My user and the other user are IAM accounts belonging to different organisations**. (I know this policy can be written more simply, but the intention is to add a check on the upload to block objects without appropriate permissions being created).

I can then use the following code to list all objects in the bucket and also to upload new objects to the bucket. This works, however the owner of the bucket has no access to the object due to Amazons default of making objects private to the creator of the object

```py
import base64
import hashlib
from boto3.session import Session


access_key = "value generated by Amazon"
secret_key = "value generated by Amazon"
bucketname = "bbb"

content_bytes = b"hello world!"
content_md5 = base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5(content_bytes).digest()).decode("utf-8")
filename = "foo.txt"

sess = Session(aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

bucket = sess.resource("s3").Bucket(bucketname)
for o in bucket.objects.all():
    print(o)

s3 = sess.client("s3")
s3.put_object(
    Bucket=bucketname,
    Key=filename,
    Body=content_bytes,
    ContentMD5=content_md5,
    # ACL="bucket-owner-full-control"  # Uncomment this line to generate error
)
```

As soon as I uncomment the ACL option, the code generates an Access Denied error message. If I redirect this to point to a bucket inside my own organisation, the ACL option succeeds and the owner of the bucket is given full permission to the object.

I'm now at a loss to figure this out, especially as Amazons own advice appears to be to do it the way I have shown.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-require-object-ownership/

Comment: Check if your user (or role) is missing `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission in **IAM**, not only bucket policy.

Comment: Thanks, Oleksii, this indeed is the extra bit I was missing! Very frustrating that permissions are defined in this fashion

Comment: I will post it as an answer so maybe someone else will find it in google, glad I helped

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the ACL of the object(s) in question, using
    aws s3api get-object-acl  --bucket <bucket> --key <prefix-and-filename> --profile <test-profile>

where test-profile is the one you are trying to use, to access the object.

You could then manually use:
    aws s3api put-object-acl  --bucket <> --key <> --acl bucket-owner-full-access --profile <>

to give access as required, note that the profile used must have sufficient access itself !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not enough to have permission in bucket policies only.

Check if your user (or role) is missing `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission in **IAM**.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `resource` methods in boto3, there can be several different API calls being made, and it isn't always obvious which calls are being made.

In comparison, when using `client` methods in boto3, there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the API call that is being made in boto3, and the API call received by AWS.

Therefore, it is likely that the `resource.put_object()` method is calling an additional API, such as `PutObjectAcl`. You can confirm this by looking in **AWS CloudTrail** and seeing which API calls are being made from your app.

In such a case, you would need the additional `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission. This would be needed if the upload process first creates the object, and *then* updates the object's Access Control List.

When using the `client` methods for uploading a file, there is also the ability to specify an ACL, which I think gets applied directly rather than requiring a second API call. Thus, using the `client` method to create the object probably would *not* require this additional permission.

Comment: Sorry, I am using the `client.put_object` method and the `ACL` argument to this method is what was failing.

Oleksii's comment has in fact solved the issue for me. It's somewhat frustrating that the security is setup this way, where the same setting has to be placed in multiple locations to work